# Hiding or disabling Database Connections in Catalog window using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, c#, catalog-window

I am working on a project that I must limit  some functionality of ArcMap based on user permissions.

Is there any way to do that ?

for example I want to disable the Database Connections in Catalog windows  by using c# in ArcObjects

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate question this poster is asking to disable the ability to access database connections, which is probably not possible as it would require overriding the systems GUI, but I could be wrong.

Comment: If you click on the options button in the Catalog window in ArcMap and go to general tab you can hide database connections, no idea how you access that programatically?

Comment: I want  to do that by using  c#  in arcobjects.In other word I need  to accomplish that issue programmatically .

Comment: Not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.  Next time arcmap is started the folder is present.

```
protected override void OnClick()
{
    try
    {
        var cont = ((IGxApplication)ArcMap.Application).Catalog as IGxObjectContainer;
        IGxObject gxObj;
        IGxObject gxRdf = null;
        var enumGx = cont.Children;
        enumGx.Reset();
        while((gxObj = enumGx.Next())!= null)
        {
            if (gxObj is IGxRemoteDatabaseFolder)
                gxRdf = gxObj;
        }
        if(gxRdf != null)
            cont.DeleteChild(gxRdf);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```